# referencing static resources in lightning components with dynamic namespaces

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, namespace

We have a lightning component thats part of our appexchange package. We have development environments with no namespace, a beta/staging package namespace, and our production package namespace. Is it possible to make the following namespace dynamic?

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.yournamespace__resourceName}" styles="{!$Resource.yournamespace__resourceName}" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: In terms of workarounds, probably worth noting that this is one of those things DX solves since it lets you have scratch orgs with the same namespace - so any solution you come up with should probably assume you won't need it once you implement a DX workflow

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make it dynamic, but you can try doing it like this:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.yournamespace1__resourceName}" styles="{!$Resource.yournamespace1__resourceName}" />
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.yournamespace2__resourceName}" styles="{!$Resource.yournamespace2__resourceName}" />
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.yournamespace3__resourceName}" styles="{!$Resource.yournamespace3__resourceName}" />
```

Since only one reference is valid in any given org, the resource would only be loaded via the valid reference.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

And there is no possible way to make it dynamic. 
I have added the namespace manually in it and then commit it to production.

You can check out the below link.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_reference.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<aura:attribute name="ns" type="String" description="pkg namespace" />
<ltng:require scripts="{! '/resource/<yourfoldername>/' + v.ns + '__' + <your resource name>}" />
```

Be sure to include any additional folders in the path with the folder name